# JDBC is not passing the root user to DriverManager.getConnection

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is my code :

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{


    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Something happened badly");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
        final String USER = "root";
        final String PASSWORD = "XXXXX";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASSWORD);    
        //String db = "CREATE DATABASE TEST1";
        String use_db = "USE football_manager";
        Statement stmt;


        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE coffees "
            + "(COF_NAME VARCHAR(30),"
            + "SUPPLIER VARCHAR(30),"
            + "PRICE FLOAT,"
            + "STOCK INTEGER)";


        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

            //stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
           // stmt.executeUpdate(db);

            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(use_db);

            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(createTable);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }                       
    }
}
```

And here is the message I keep getting in my console:

> SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database

As you can see the user name has been left blank. I'm using Eclipse Luna. This worked fine when I used Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Don't use `System.err.println(ex.getMessage())` (and whatever around it). It's way better to use `ex.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Thanks will do that for future

Comment: See: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
```

You're obtaining a second connection object but not sending the user credentials. I'm not sure why you want/need to open a second connection, use the first one.

Comment: Oh my God thank you!! That was absolutely killing me! That seems to work now! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Leduigs: the usual way to show appreciation for an answer is to accept it by clicking the checkmark under the vote total